# What's the best approach to copy Macintosh data between two NAS devices?

Tags: linux, mac, nas, metadata, data-transfer

I have an old NAS formatted to Ext4, but which I primarily access from Macintoshs via AFP. It therefore has a bit of Macintosh-only metadata (which only seems to be visible when accessing via AFP).

I now want to copy all the data to a new NAS (also Ext4-formatted). In the past I’ve done this by mounting the two drives via AFP and using Finder to copy, but that's fraught with problems. Is there a better way to do this—such as SCP—that will preserve the Macintosh metadata?

Comment: On a foreign filesystem like ext4, all the Mac metadata, including legacy Mac file "resource forks" (which aren't always just metadata) is stored in dotfiles such as `.DS_Store`, and, for file `example.txt`, the file `._example.txt`. Any copy that copies all the dotfiles should copy all the metadata. I'm not aware of any situation where Mac metadata would be stored in the native metadata structures of a foreign filesystem like ext4. The only filesystem in which the Mac stores its metadata natively is the Mac native HFS+ filesystem (including the journaled and case-sensitive variants of HFS+).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rsync!  It copies all.

```
rsync -arlH --progress /Path/to/Source/ /Path/to/Destination/
```

- **-a** for archive
- **-r** for recursive
- **-l** for sym-links
- **-H** for hard links
- **--progress** to show your progress

Also, if you want to be sure you include your “dotfiles” be sure to not use the * wildcard.

Comment: also has the benefit of resuming failed transfers, which I hadn't initially considered

Answer (score 2):

> It therefore has a bit of Macintosh-only metadata (which only seems to
>   be visible when accessing via AFP).

Small thing—but also a big thing—in this respect: Metadata is data about data. So metadata embedded into a file will be viewable anywhere, anyhow without the use of special tools. Go ahead and see for yourself by downloading some images across the web from various places; chances are you will hit at least one image that has stored camera metadata in it that came from the camera source, was retained in image processing, was retained in it’s transfer to a foreign file system on a website and is now retained on your desktop.

So when you describe “Macintosh-only metadata” what you are talking about is Macintosh-only data that is stored in resource forks and that is considered Macintosh extended metadata [as explained here](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1762250&seqNum=5):

> Resource forks, dating back to the original Mac OS, are the legacy
>   metadata technology in the Macintosh operating system. To simplify the
>   user experience, Apple created a forked file system to make complex
>   items, such as applications, appear as a single icon. Forked file
>   systems, like Mac OS Extended, allow multiple pieces of data to appear
>   as a single item in the file system. In this case, a file will appear
>   as a single item, but it is actually composed of two separate pieces,
>   a data fork and a resource fork. This also allows the Mac OS to
>   support standard file types in the data fork, while the extra
>   Mac-specific information resides in the resource fork. For many years
>   the Mac OS has relied on forked files for storing both data and
>   associated metadata.

So it might sound pedantic, but you need to be careful since “metadata” that is not OS idiosyncratic will always be copied when a file is copied. But idiosyncratic metadata like Macintosh extended metadata is a whole other thing.

That said, there is nothing wrong with [`rsync`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html) but it’s a command line tool that can be confusing in usage in cases like this; copying Macintsoh specific data. The most basic bit of confusion: The version of `rsync` installed on most Macs dates back to 2006—version 2.6.9—while most modern Linux/Unix installs use a version in the 3.0.x range. Not to mention I believe the Mac OS X version is a custom version idiosyncratic to Mac OS X only. Which all means you might read `rsync` tutorials online that refer to functionality your Mac OS X `rsync` doesn’t have or implements differently.

Which is not to say that `rsync` can’t be used, but if you don’t want to stress too much or get a headache too quickly, your best bet is to use a canned solution such as [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com). Both of those tools use `rsync` in their core, but make the process tons more high-level/Mac-friendly.

Personally, I used to use [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) regularly for system backups, but then got a bit tired of it. I prefer [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) nowadays since it’s quite solid, stable and allows full disk as well as folder only copies of data that are picture perfect clones in all respects.

Comment: I've accepted the rsync answer because that doesn't actually require me to use the Mac as a go-between.